# Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:text' - Android MVVM

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I am constantly getting this error in android MVVM architecture.I tried deleting .idea,igradle ,gradle folders but it did not work .I even tried restarting studio with invalidate cache,this also did not work.please help.

below is the sample code

```
public class TestViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    MutableLiveData<String> test = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public TestViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<String> getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(MutableLiveData<String> test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="in.raji.bills.billsreminder.viewmodels.TestViewModel"
            />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="in.raji.bills.billsreminder.viewmodels.TestViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:context=".MonthlyFragment">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Enter title"
            android:text="@{viewModel.test}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: 1) you don't have to have the `<import>` when you use the instance of viewModel (you would need the import, if you used any static stuff [constant, class, enum, ...]) 

2) I think the code generator may be confused because you have variable `test` and getter/setter for it .. I'd try to make the variable `public final` and remove the setters (or make it `private`?) 

3) if you want to have two-way databinding .. you have forgot `@=` .. use `android:text="@={viewModel.test}"`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

**LiveData can be used as observable field in from Android Studio 3.1.** This is a bug of old Android Studio, please update your Android Studio. [Check Release Notes](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/09/android-studio-32-release-candidate-3.html).

**Suggestion**

- Remove `<import type="in.raji.bills.billsreminder.viewmodels.TestViewModel"/>`
- You can make `MutableLiveData<String> test` private.